# Task management in C# with IIS hosting WCF service

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf, task-parallel-library, task

I have WCF service with 32-bit version hosted in the IIS. In which, I used the following approach to create the task to execute my operation parallel ( do with the database calculation or making external call to third parties).

```
   List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
    Task parentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
        {
            var task = new Task(() => Do(), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
            taskList.Add(task);
        }
    });


    foreach (Task t in taskList)
    {
        t.Start();
    }

    parentTask.Wait(20000);
```

Using above code, I create the approx 140 task with a single request to my service. There are an approx 10 requests per second to my application.

I am facing the issue like that most of tasks are not executed before my parent thread waits over when it going to perform heavy operations then tasks are not getting enough CPU means not invoking in parallel task.

I just want to know is the best way to handle multi-thread. I have come across with many articles and Task.Factory.StartNew always uses the thread pool concepts why my task initiates and running taking more than 20 seconds time with the high concurrent request.

In this case, I assumed that all operations are completed before the parent waits overs. Is that best way to go with cancellation of tasks instead of wait?

Is 32-bit application and 64-bit application have the significant impact with .Net framework 4.0 with task management?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Didn't look too closely, but perhaps replacing parentTask.Wait(20000) with Task.WaitAll(taskList) is what you're after. In which case, there may be no need for your parentTask instance.

Answer (score 3):

There is always "The Best Way". in your case try

taskList.WaitAll(); instead of  parentTask.Wait(20000);

Answer (score 2):

In regards to your second question:

> Is 32-bit application and 64-bit application have the significant impact with .Net framework 4.0 with task management?

The answer is no.  A task is executed on a threadpool thread.  A CPU can execute one thread at a time regardless of whether it is running a 32- or 64-bit process.  The size of the threadpool CAN be tweaked, but it is not recommended.  There is a complicated calculation that the .NET framework goes through to determine the size of the threadpool, which is based on the number of CPUs/cores, the clock speed, and some other parameters.

Having too many threads executing at once is not efficient because managing and switching between threads requires resources.  If you get a bunch of CPU-bound threads all queued up, then considerable CPU time can be consumed just switching back and forth between them, and never getting any work done (kind of like when you have 7 project managers stopping by your desk every 10 minutes asking for status updates), causing yet more threads to be created as more work is requested, until your server pegs out at 100% and grinds to a halt.

Answer (score 0):

Since, parent task should wait for child tasks then you should be using `WaitAll` method of Task class which waits for all of the provided Task objects to complete execution.

Created the sample program to demonstrate the same :

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {   
        Console.WriteLine("Starting Parent Task");
         List<Task> taskList = new List<Task>();
         Task parentTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
         {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++)
            {
                var task = new Task(() => Console.WriteLine("Task Running : " + Task.CurrentId), TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent);
                taskList.Add(task);
            }

            foreach (Task t in taskList)
            {
                t.Start();
            }

            Task.WaitAll(taskList.ToArray());

         });


        Console.WriteLine("Parent Task Ending");

    }
}
```

Created [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Yi2mw6) dotnet fiddle. You can check the output of it in fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have read this (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997417.aspx) already. If you do not use any features, provided by Attached tasks approach (exception and cancellation propagation) you can do, as **Atom** just suggested **taskList.WaitAll(20000)**. But keep in mind that after this Wait() went through, your tasks are still running, if you didn't implement cancellation explicitly.

It matters also what `Do()` is. Tasks are using ThreadPool and you can manage the number of threads in it. [You can specify the number of threads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.setmaxthreads.aspx) in it. If your `Do()` is computation, you are always using **worker** threads. But if in this call you consume another service, **you should do that asynchronously**. In this way you will be using **I/O completion ports** and appropriate I/O  threads, which almost does not consume any system resources. To run service call asynchronously you may use Async version of client methods with Task result or Begin/End+IAsyncResult. in Second case you may use [TaskFactory.FromAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskfactory.fromasync(v=vs.110).aspx) to convert it into the task.